# common emitter problem

Tags: transistors

I have this problem to solve where I1 = 6mA, beta=125 and Vbe =0.6V

[image]

So far I have solved the following,

**a. How circuit works?**

Circuit works as a stable output voltage source. This is caused by the negative feedback through the series resistor R2. If I1 increases then IR1 also increases, thus rising the base voltage of Q1. Since, Vbe is increased, thus collector current I1 is also increased, such the excess current I is shunted through Q1 reducing the effective current through R2 to maintaining constant voltage.

**b. Output DC voltage**
**Ib** = Ic/beta = **48uA**

therefore, **Vout** = Vbe + VR2 = 0.6V + (100K * 48uA) = **5.4V**

**c. O/P impedance**

I made the AC equivalent circuit as following,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSmURj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This means that **Zout = 0** is it right?

**d. One measure to reduce the Zout**

According to my AC model of the DC circuit, Zout is 0 so why do I need to reduce it  more, Or I did something wrong in question c?

**e. Typical disadvantage**

Is it the shunting of I1 to maintain constant Vout when I1 increases?

Comment: What do you mean by "shunted through Q1"? If you are considering Vbe as constant, then an increase in base current would force Vout to be Vbe + R2*Ib, so how does this act like a stable constant output source?

Comment: Thanks Sherrellbc for the comment I have modified my answer.

Comment: Regarding your comment below about the derivation, you must consider the effects of an incremental increase in I1 on Vo (by how much does it change) and the relationships between the base and collector currents. And recall `Rout = Vout/Iout`.

Answer (score 1):

No, the output impedance is not zero. To figure it out, try increasing or decreasing the value of the current source by some small increment, and then calculating the resulting change in output voltage. ΔV / ΔI gives you the effective impedance of the resistor+transistor circuit, which is also the output impedance, since the impedance of the current source itself is infinite.

You'll find that the resistor and transistor together act like a simple resistor that has the value R2 / β. I'll leave it to you to derive this mathematically.

Comment: Shouldn't it be that the output resistance be calculated using as Vo/Io? How is the collector current also the output current? Output to where? There is no load. Too many questions.

Comment: @sherrellbc: I don't know what to tell you, because your questions aren't making any sense to me. I think you need to sit down and do the same DC analysis of the circuit that the OP is doing. Then, you might be able to formulate some specific questions.

Comment: The confusing point here was the definition of output current (to find Ro =  Vo/Io) with this circuit. If the emitter current is considered as the output, then you arrive at `Ro = R2/(beta+1)`, but if the collector current is considered the output then you find `Ro = R2/beta`.

Comment: @sherrellbc: Why would you consider the emitter current to be the output? The emitter is grounded, the OP clearly specified this to be a common-emitter circuit, and the collector is clearly labeled as the output node.

Answer (score 1):

Your first answer may be what they are looking for, if one assumes Vbe and \$\beta\$ are constant.

The second is slightly off, as you failed to take into account the base current.

The third is way off. It's approximately 100K/\$\beta\$ but I'll let you work out the exact value.

Comment: The OP has for the second answer `Vo = Vbe + R2*Ib`, what did he miss here? Also, what is considered the "output" current here, as there is no load to speak of. If you consider the emitter current as the output current then I was able to derive `Ro = R2/(beta+1)`, but how can the emitter current be considered the output?

Comment: @sherrellbc The collector current is not 6mA/\$\beta\$, as he fails to take into account the base current. The 'output current' is whatever you draw from (or push into) the collector-R2-current source node. It's an output voltage, so you need to analyze the change in output voltage for a small change in output current. The ratio of the two is the output resistance.

Comment: Hello Spehro, In the second question I have used the base current 48uA to calculate the Vout. Why is this wrong? In my third question I noticed that my AC equivalent circuit was wrong so i corrected it.

Comment: The collector current is not exactly 6mA/\$\beta\$ so the base current is not exactly 48uA. Some of the 6mA flows into the base.

Comment: Please make changes by adding edits after, otherwise the comments we make will not make any sense to others looking at it later.

Comment: Hello Sherrellbc, I tried to derive the formula for the Zout but was not able to do so, is there some reference I could used?

Comment: Thanks for informing Spehro, I will make sure of this next time

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, what would be answers to (d) and (e) in the OP? An obvious way to reduce output impedance would be to reduce R2 as the output impedance is a direct function of it. Perhaps a disadvantage being it must be driven with a current source which can be complex to implement.